# Include a framework into another one, is it possible?

Tags: ios, frameworks

I'm creating a framework for iOS and one of my classes uses the framework MobileCoreServices in order to obtain the MIME type of a file given its path. The problem is that I must also include the MobileCoreServices in each app which uses my framework, also if the specific app does not need to use classes and methods of that framework.

Is there a solution? Something like including the MobileCoreServices framework in mine? So that the final user does not need to know which he has to include it.

Comment: add and try.. for me I could add some of my core services. and .a files were also added. just not too sure about this but I think that must be possible.