# How to make XCode add the linked project headers and implementaion files to the static library and framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a static library project and in that project I linked a .xcodeproj to the source code so I can update easily actually and to not copy and paste files in the static library project for easy update.

The purpose thought it's to embed this .xcodeproj with my code into the result static library or .framework that I will build using a script.

Although I can see that there is nothing added in the compile sources or the copy header files which I added. If I try to add with drag and drop files from the linked project to my static library build phases copy header section it copies the file to my project again, but I don't want this. 
And if I add a header file `#import` to one of my public headers and try to use the static library to the client project it complains that the header is not found!

So, in the end, what I want is the whole linked project files to be copied in the resulting static library or .framework with the scripts and target I have.

Is this possible to achieve, I think I miss some project setting that I'm not aware about that will see and copy all header and implementation files to my result static library or .framework?

Is my approach overall correct? I don't think that there is no option to use a linked project in a static library and embed it when the build is happening since I am using it in my project!

I could add the .framework of the third party component too and merge to my static library. I have created this question earlier today. [Is it possible to include a .framework in a .framework and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113316/is-it-possible-to-include-a-framework-in-a-framework-and-how)

Regards.

Comment: A static library is just a collection of compiled binary files in a single container.  If you want to distribute other files with it, they have to be in some kind of support folder.  Frequently, headers are in an "include" directory.

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate. I actually need to embed it to a .framework. This is my target.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your #import-not-found issue is a linker issue, but...

Make sure to use the -ObjC flag in "Other Linker Flags" in the library's Build Settings. This gets the linker to build everything in the library.

Mentioned here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/configuration.html

And also make sure you link in the library in the build settings for the project that needs it.

Comment: I have -ObjC all along. My problem actually is that i can't embed the linked project to a .framework not in the static library. If I create a static library then it's fine.